# Characteristic functions of multivariate distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, positive-definite, characteristic-functions

Bochner’s theorem  tells us each positive semidefinite function is the characteristic function of a probability measure. (see, for example, [these lecture notes](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matsr/ProbI/Lecture7.pdf)). In combination with it's converse, which follows from associated definitions, we can see that positive definite functions are in one to one correspondence with random variables' probability distributions.

All the resources I can find online treat only the univariate case, but I'm interested in joint distributions of random variables. Could someone help me understand how this result generalizes or fails to generalize to the multivariate case?

Comment: The converse of Bochner's theorem in high dimensions (if $X$ is a real random *vector*, then its characteristic function is positive semi-definite) has a proof virtually identical to the one dimensional case. Did you try extending the proof in the linked lecture notes to higher dimensions? If so, did you run into any issues?

Comment: There are many books that deal with characteristic functions in higher dimensions. Volume 2 of Feller's book has a section devoted to this.

Comment: @parsiad It seemed like the proof would transfer, though I hadn't had a chance to look in any depth. Good to know that it does!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, that looks very promising!